# How do I get Intellij`s Android emulator in the background?

Tags: intellij-idea

... it`s driving me crazy - the android emulator window in Intellij is always on top. How can I switch that off?  After each hot reload, I  have to minimize the emulator in order to continue coding. If not, the emulator will block a large part of the editor.

I am feeling seriously dumb, but for the sake of my life, I don`t find the setting to change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Emulator always on top` option is disabled:

[image]